# Using std::thread or CreateThread()?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was revising my codes when doing a project that I developed when I started coding in C/C++.

It's about threading. In the tutorials I read (which were from 2006) they said that, when developing for Windows, one could use CreateThread() to create threads. Is Using this function better than using std::thread?

Is it faster also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In applications that load the CRT (as most C/C++ are) you can't use `CreateThread`, as per spec:

> A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the [`_beginthreadex` and `_endthreadex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.120).aspx) functions for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread; this requires the use of the multithreaded version of the CRT. If a thread created using CreateThread calls the CRT, the CRT may terminate the process in low-memory conditions.

`std::thread` on the other hand will do the right thing.